# C++ Builder 11.2 assigning C++ method to Delphi event

Tags: delphi, c++builder

We have an older project with mixed C++/Delphi code. We are trying to compile it with the latest C++Builder.

This code was OK with RAD Studio 10.1:

```cpp
NewObject->OnDraw = (TDrawEvent)&(CObj->MyVRMLShapeDraw);
```

Edit: actual declarations:

```pascal
TDrawEvent = procedure (Sender: TGLObject; Face: GLenum; Draft: boolean; State: TGLDrawState ) of object;  

private
  FOnDraw: TDrawEvent;   
published
  property OnDraw: TDrawEvent read FOnDraw write FOnDraw;
```

```cpp
class TManager : public TBaseObject {
public:
    void __fastcall MyVRMLShapeDraw(TGLObject *Sender, DWORD Face, bool Draft, char DrawState);
```

Where `NewObject` is a class instance from a Delphi class, `TDrawEvent` is a Delphi event method type (`TMethod` basically with some parameters), `CObj` is our C++ object, `MyDraw` is its C++ method.

`TGLDrawState` is an `enum` with a few values.

The latest C++Builder compiler drops this error message:

> [bcc64 Error] xy.cpp(1021): cannot compile this unexpected cast lvalue yet

How can we solve this? Is it possible at all to call a C++ method from Delphi code in the usual event handler method style?

**EDIT:** I solved it with wrapping the call in a global function, but if someone knows the elegant syntax of this, it would be appreciated.

**EDIT:** My mistake - the newer 11.2 compiler required using `unsigned` instead of `DWORD`, and `glclasses::TGLDrawState` instead of `char` in the C++ method parameter list. Older compilers accepted less strict type matching.

Comment: You don't need the typecast in the first place. If the signature of `MyDraw` matches `OnDraw` correctly then`NewObject->OnDraw = CObj->MyDraw;` should work fine in all versions of C++Builder. Please provide the actual declarations of `TDrawEvent`, `OnDraw`, and `MyDraw`.

Comment: Also, please show your "solution" (which should have been posted as an answer instead of an edit).

Comment: I edited the post and also found my mistake - newer compiler is more strict on type matching in function parameter list.

Comment: I deleted the hackish workaround answer as that was also based on the now correct function parameter list.

Comment: Is there a reason why your C++ code is not using the *exact* types that are actually specified in the Delphi declaration? `MyVRMLShapeDraw` should look like `void __fastcall MyVRMLShapeDraw(TGLObject* Sender, GLenum Face, bool Draft, TGLDrawState State);`

Comment: No, as I wrote that was my (our) mistake. C++ was not so strict when we started this project a long time ago.... yes with exact same type there's no problem.